# Show loading progress when making JSF Ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, progress-bar, loading

How can I show some loading message when making request using `<f:ajax>`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're not already using a 3rd party component library which could already have a ready-made component for that, such as [PrimeFaces](https://primefaces.org) with [`<p:ajaxStatus>`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml), then you can use the JSF-provided JavaScript [`faces.ajax.addOnEvent()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/jsdoc/faces.ajax.html#.addOnEvent) function (and eventually also [`faces.ajax.addOnError()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/jsdoc/faces.ajax.html#.addOnError)) to hook a function on ajax events.

Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
<script>
    faces.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
        var ajaxstatus = data.status; // Can be "begin", "complete" and "success"
        var ajaxloader = document.getElementById("ajaxloader");

        switch (ajaxstatus) {
            case "begin": // This is called right before ajax request is been sent.
                ajaxloader.style.display = 'block';
                break;
    
            case "complete": // This is called right after ajax response is received.
                ajaxloader.style.display = 'none';
                break;
    
            case "success": // This is called when ajax response is successfully processed.
                // NOOP.
                break;
        }
    });
</script>

<img id="ajaxloader" src="ajaxloader.gif" style="display: none;" />
```

See also section [13.3.5.2](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/jakarta-faces-4.0.html#a6790) of the [Jakarta Faces 4.0 specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/jakarta-faces-4.0.html):

> #### 13.3.5.2 Monitoring Events For All Ajax Requests
>
> The JavaScript API provides the `faces.ajax.addOnEvent` function that can be used to register a JavaScript function
> that will be notified when any Ajax request/response event occurs. Refer to Section 14.4 “Registering Callback
> Functions” for more details. The `faces.ajax.addOnEvent` function accepts a JavaScript function argument that will be
> notified when events occur during any Ajax request/response event cycle. The implementation must
> ensure the JavaScript function that is registered must be called in accordance with the events outlined in
> Section TABLE 14-3 “Events”.

Note: in case you're still using JSF 3.0 or older, then use `jsf.ajax` namespace instead of `faces.ajax` as in `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(...)`.

Comment: @BalusC, your answer is great! But I wonder whether this can be applied selectively, ie. whether it might apply only to certain ajax components, while others should be ignored?

Comment: _Here's a basic kickoff example:_ Indeed. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

richfaces has a very easy to use component that I use like this:

```
<a4j:status startText="" stopText="" onstart="showAjaxActive();" onstop="hideAjaxActive();"/>
```