# Ajax Loading picture position above content

Tags: css, ajax

I am using the Ajax Loading picture found here : [Show loading progress when making JSF Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880843/show-loading-message-when-making-ajax-request-using-jsf-2-0) to show image loading when an ajax is between begin,complete,success status.

I would like to know how to make the image appear above all content and in the center of the screen like any loading picture in almost all websites.

```
<div id="ajaxloader" style="display: none;">
<h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/gload.gif"></h:graphicImage>
</div>
```

Ajax script

```
<script>
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
        var ajaxstatus = data.status; // Can be "begin", "complete" and "success"
        var ajaxloader = document.getElementById("ajaxloader");

        switch (ajaxstatus) {
            case "begin": // This is called right before ajax request is been sent.
                ajaxloader.style.display = 'block';
                break;

            case "complete": // This is called right after ajax response is received.
                ajaxloader.style.display = 'none';
                break;

            case "success": // This is called when ajax response is successfully processed.
                // NOOP.
                break;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a combination of `position:fixed` and `transform: translate`. I don't know what `h:graphicImage` is, so the example below uses a standard `img` tag, but the important bit is the inline style on your `ajaxloader` div:

```js
var ajaxloader = document.getElementById("ajaxloader");
var i = 0;

function toggleLoader() {
  var displayStyle;
  if (++i % 2) {
    displayStyle = 'block';
  } else {
    displayStyle = 'none';
  }
  ajaxloader.style.display = displayStyle;
}

document.getElementById("showLoader").addEventListener('click', toggleLoader);
```

```html
<div id="ajaxloader" style="display: none;position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%); z-index: 1;">
<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=14&txt=Loading...&w=100&h=100"/>
</div>
<button id="showLoader">Toggle load graphic</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, the centring is working, but image is shown under other divs

Comment: Updated answer to add a `z-index`; you'll need to make sure it's sufficiently high for your use. If that still doesn't work, you will need to ensuring that your loading div is a child of `body` to ensure you're not getting caught in an unexpected stacking context.

Comment: Yes now all works like expected, by the way, h:graphicImage is the img tag for the Java Server Faces