# Waiting until an XHR request has completed with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xmlhttprequest, cucumber-java

From what I can determine, there don't appear to be any simple answers to this via searching.

**Scenario**

A JSF page contains a form.  There is a dropdown element which, on change, sends an XHR (rather than jQuery) Ajax call to update the DOM.  For all intents, the update is indiscernible - it still has the same fields, but re-loads them.  As all of this is done with JSF, it's best to assume I can't amend/modify the JS or functionality of the page.

Using Selenium/Cucumber, I need to apply a step that will 'wait' until the XHR has completed.  This **does not use jQuery**, so `jQuery.active` returns `0` throughout the request.

I also can't use any 'wait until' methods on any DOM elements, as they don't change - simply 're-construct' after the XHR completes.  There are no other loading 'cues', like a Spinner, either.

Developer tools in Chrome seems to be able to time the start and completion of the XHR in 'Network',  but I don't know if this is done via another layer - rather than any value I can return via the console.

Any methods I've found so far seem to rely on JS injection - is this not going to be possible?

Comment: If the DOM is being reloaded, an element would become "Stale", you should be able to grab one of the elements on the page before the Ajax begins and check it until it is "Stale" and then grab that element again and when it is not "Stale", possibly use that as an indication that the DOM has been re-loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by 'js injection'? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880843/show-loading-progress-when-making-jsf-ajax-request help? It talks about adding 'global' ajax events, sort of what you'd do with jquery as well.

Comment: @RyanWilson - Obvious now you mention it! Thanks!
Resolved by using a wait until `ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf( getWebDriver().findElement( By.id( webElement ) ) )`, followed by a wait until `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( By.id( webElement ) )`

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, this was resolved via a wait until 
`ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf( getWebDriver().findElement( By.id( webElement ) ) )`, followed by a wait until 
`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( By.id( webElement )`

Comment: Glad that this helped you. +1 from me.