# Jsf ajax not found in javascript file (jsf.ajax)

Tags: jsf

Hello : I see that answer an I think I can use it in my code :[Show loading progress when making JSF Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880843/show-loading-progress-when-making-jsf-ajax-request)
But when I use this method in javascript code :

```js
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data) {
    var ajaxstatus = data.status; // Can be "begin", "complete" and "success"
    var ajaxloader = document.getElementById("ajaxloader");

    switch (ajaxstatus) {
        case "begin":
            console.log("Begin");
            break;

        case "complete":
            console.log("Completed");
            break;

        case "success":
            console.log("Suc");
            break;
    }
});
```

the console show me :

```
DpsMain.js:58 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsf is not defined
    at DpsMain.js:58:1
```

Is that changed in JSF ?
or I missing something?
Versions :
GlassFish 7.0.3 Jakarta EE 10
JDK 17

The goal of my code is show loading entire the components and User View in safe way and easiest way! for minimum change in my codes or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops , I founded!
In jakarta changed name into faces
so I need to change Jsf into faces , Like blow

```
    faces.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data) {
    var ajaxstatus = data.status; // Can be "begin", "complete" and "success"
    var ajaxloader = document.getElementById("ajaxloader");

    switch (ajaxstatus) {
        case "begin":
            console.log("Begin");
            break;

        case "complete":
            console.log("Completed");
            break;

        case "success":
            console.log("Suc");
            break;
    }
});
```

now its work!
Sorry if asked a stupid question.